# Accessing "dot" namespaced services in Twig view

Tags: php, twig, silex

I know that I can access registered services by using the dot notation in a Twig template (example `app.request.host`). However, if I've created my own namespaced service (in this case `tagframe.photoservice`), when I try to access it, I am given an error that the method "tagframe" doesn't exist on the object "Silex\Application". Is it possible to access services that have been dot namespaced? In other words, a service that I would normally access using $app['tagframe.photoservice'] in the controller?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `app.tagframe.photoservice` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just like accessing array:

```
{{ app["tagframe.photoservice"].resizePhoto() }}
```