# How to get an element from an array in Twig when the key contains a dot?

Tags: symfony, twig, silex

I have many configuration options inside an array called 'app', which is set as a global in Twig.

The problem is some of the keys contain a '.', so this fails:

```
{{ app.cookie.path }}
```

So far this seems like the only way to make it work:

```
{{ app.raw('cookie.path') }}
```

But it's obviously not very accurate in its semantics, since raw is meant to be used to get the closures defined with shared(), not normal parameters.

Is there another way to fetch an array element with a key that contains a dot?

Comment: Did you try `app["cookie.path"]`?

Comment: @Maerlyn I thought I did. It works, thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing "dot" namespaced services in Twig view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12538766/accessing-dot-namespaced-services-in-twig-view)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use:

```
{{ app["cookie.path"] }}
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you should have a look at the `attribute` [twig function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html) :

```
{{ attribute(app, 'cookie.path') }}
```